# Android: Exception Unmarshalling unknown type

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have to pass a ArrayList from one activity to another activity. So I use

```
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("Items",sendinglist);
```

And I get the sendinglist through

```
ArrayList<GeoItem> revd = new ArrayList<GeoItem>();
        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (b != null)
            revd = b.getParcelableArrayList("Items");
Log.i("Element details",revd.get(0).getLatitude()+"");// Error
```

But i cant access the GeoItem object in that list.
**UPDATE** the class based on the answers...

My GeoItem class is

public class GeoItem implements Parcelable, Serializable {

```
/** id of item. */
protected long id_;
/** item location in GeoPoint. */
// protected GeoPoint location_;
/** selection state flag. true if selected. */
protected boolean isSelected_;
protected int latitude;
protected int longitude;
protected String incident_no;
protected String title;
protected String date;
protected String address;

/**
 * @param id
 *            item id.
 * @param latitudeE6
 *            latitude of the item in microdegrees (degrees * 1E6).
 * @param longitudeE6
 *            longitude of the item in microdegrees (degrees * 1E6).
 */
public GeoItem(long id, int latitudeE6, int longitudeE6, String inc_no,
        String tlt, String dates, String addr) {
    id_ = id;
    // location_ = new GeoPoint(latitudeE6, longitudeE6);
    isSelected_ = false;
    incident_no = inc_no;
    title = tlt;
    date = dates;
    address = addr;
    latitude=latitudeE6;
    longitude=longitudeE6;
}

public long getId_() {
    return id_;
}

public void setId_(long id_) {
    this.id_ = id_;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public void setIncident_no(String incident_no) {
    this.incident_no = incident_no;
}

public int getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(int latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

public int getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(int longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

/**
 * @param src
 *            source GeoItem
 */
public GeoItem(GeoItem src) {
    id_ = src.id_;
    // location_ = new
    // GeoPoint(src.location_.getLatitudeE6(),src.location_.getLongitudeE6());
    isSelected_ = src.isSelected_;
}

/**
 * @param src
 *            source Parcel
 */
public GeoItem(Parcel src) {
    id_ = src.readLong();
    // location_ = new GeoPoint(src.readInt(), src.readInt());
    isSelected_ = src.readInt() == 0 ? false : true;
    address = src.readString();
    date = src.readString();
}

/* describeContents */
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

/**
 * getId
 * 
 * @return id of the item.
 */
public long getId() {
    return id_;
}

public String getIncident_no() {
    return incident_no;
}

/**
 * setId
 * 
 * @param id
 *            of the item.
 */
public void setId(long id) {
    id_ = id;
    ;
}

/**
 * getLocation
 * 
 * @return GeoPoint of the item.
 * 
 *         public GeoPoint getLocation() { return location_; }
 */
/**
 * isSelected
 * 
 * @return true if the item is in selected state.
 */
public boolean isSelected() {
    return isSelected_;
}

/**
 * setSelect
 * 
 * @param flg
 *            flag to be set.
 */
public void setSelect(boolean flg) {
    isSelected_ = flg;
}

/**
 * Parcelable.Creator
 */
public static final Parcelable.Creator<GeoItem> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<GeoItem>() {
    public GeoItem createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new GeoItem(in);
    }

    public GeoItem[] newArray(int size) {
        return new GeoItem[size];
    }
};

/**
 * writeToParcel
 * 
 * @param parcel
 *            Parcel to be written.
 * @param flags
 *            flag.
 */
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int flags) {
    parcel.writeLong(id_);
    parcel.writeString(address);
    parcel.writeString(date);
    parcel.writeInt(latitude);
    parcel.writeInt(longitude);
    int flg = isSelected_ ? 1 : 0;
    parcel.writeInt(flg);
}


}
```

Please provide me the best way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My actual task is to send the list of GeoItems object through intent. Also My GeoItems class is serializable . Obviously list of serializable object is also serialibale So I used,

```
Intent listview = new Intent(context, ReportList.class);
            Bundle send = new Bundle();
            send.putSerializable("Items", (Serializable) items);
            listview.putExtras(send);
            context.startActivity(listview);
```

where items is a list of GeoIems objects

And in receiving activity,

```
 Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        if (b != null) {
            data = (List<GeoItem>) b.getSerializable("Items");
        }
```

where data is a list of GeoIems objects

Without using Parceable interface, now i can set my list of serializable objects through intent to next activity

Answer (score 1):

[`GeoPoint`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/GeoPoint) is not a `Parceable` therefore it can be marshalled. You may want to save the data somehow without `GeoPoint` or extend `GeoPoint` so it implements `Parceable`

Comment: I have removed that GeoPoint from my GeoItem class, instead i add 2 members like latitude and longitude. But still same error

Answer (score 1):

```
**To pass an arraylist  of Category to another activity,** 



 intent i = new Intent(_av.getContext(), ItemList.class);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putParcelableArrayList("categories", categories);
    b.putInt("index", _index);
    i.putExtras(b);
    startActivityForResult(i, ITEM_LIST);

**To retrieve the data,**

Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();

ArrayList<Category> cats = b.getParcelableArrayList("categories");
int index = b.getInt("index");
```